# net::ERR_ABORTED javascript

Tags: javascript, php, calendar, datetimepicker

I want to make a datetime picker in php using javascript. I followed a tutorial and my code is this :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jquery.datemepicker.min.css">

<script src="javascript/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>


<input id="datetime">

<script>    
    $("#datetime").datetimepicker();
    </script>
```

But chrome seems to ignore the .css file , so its only printing text. Chrome gives this error :

> calendar_index.php:3 GET
>   http://localhost/css/jquery.datemepicker.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED

I cant find what is wrong here.

Comment: Can you please let me know the exact path of css file you are trying to include.

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\calendar\css\jquery.datemepicker.min.css

Comment: Please provide the entire path,do let me know if it works : <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\wamp64\www\calendar\css\jquery.datemepicker.min.css">

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work :/

Comment: Please try this: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery.datemepicker.min.css">

Comment: doesnt work either ..

Comment: First load all the javascripts and then try to include css.

Comment: nothing .. but its okei. Ill find an other way. Thank you :D